# Setting `auto-save-file-name-transforms` has the wrong effect: Auto-save files are stored in Emacs config directory

Tags: files, auto-save

Assume I have the file `~/Documents/bla.org`.  Now I open a buffer that visits the file `~/Documents/bla.org`.

I check the value of the (buffer-local) variable `buffer-auto-save-file-name`, and it reads `/home/berber/Documents/#bla.org#`.

Now I run the following code:

```
(let ((save-files-directory (file-name-concat user-emacs-directory "auto-save")))
  (make-directory save-files-directory :parents)
  (setq auto-save-file-name-transforms
    `((".*" ,save-files-directory t))))
```

If I now open a buffer that visits the file `~/Documents/bla.org`, the value of `buffer-auto-save-file-name` reads `/home/berber/.config/emacs/#!home!berber!Documents!bla.org#`.  This is the wrong directory, obviously.

When I check the variable `auto-save-file-name-transforms`, I get `((".*" "~/.config/emacs/auto-save" t))`, which sounds right, but as seen above, it doesn't do the right thing...  Yes, the directory `/home/berber/.config/emacs/auto-save` exists, and yes, I have done this with `emacs -Q`.

What could my problem be?

I am using Emacs 28.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that the directory name contains a trailing `/`:

```el
(let ((save-files-directory
          (file-name-concat user-emacs-directory
                               "auto-save/"))) ;;; <-- add trailing slash 
  (make-directory save-files-directory :parents)
  (setq auto-save-file-name-transforms
    `((".*" ,save-files-directory t))))
```

Comment: ugh thanks.  i thought i have tried this a bunch of times.  but now it works.  hm, maybe there was something else wrong then.

Comment: I didn't investigate this (I just tried it and it worked), but it feels like a (small) bug to me. If I find some time, I'll see if I can get to the bottom of it and maybe submit a bug report.